# Google oauth2 works with one time code generated from Android but not working for code generated from JS SDK

Tags: android, authentication, google-oauth

I am trying to authenticate the user using oauth2 api from Google. There are 2 platforms, Android and Web. For new users, I am fetching the one-time auth code on the client and sending it to the server on both platforms. Once server receives the code, it is fetching the access token and after that, the user details. The server is able to fetch the token from the one-time auth code sent from Android device, but it is failing for the code sent from Web.

This is my code snippet in JS for fetching one-time auth code..

```
gauth2.grantOfflineAccess({
        'scope': 'profile email',
        'redirect_uri': 'postmessage'
    }).then(function(e){
        if(!e){
            // Error
        }
        else{
            console.log('Auth code: '+e.code);
        }
    });
```

On server side, this is the POST request that I am doing to fetch the token from one-time code..

```
post_data = {'code': one_time_code, 'client_id': settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID, 'client_secret': settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET, 'grant_type': 'authorization_code'}
req = urllib2.Request("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token", data=urllib.urlencode(post_data), headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
req.get_method = lambda: 'POST'
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
if res.code == 200:
    print "response 200 : "
else:
    print "Access Token Validation Return Code: ", res.code
```

This web service call returns 200 and token when the auth-code is generated from Android. When it is sent from web, the same method throws the following error..

> Error: 400, invalid request; missing parameter 'redirect_uri'

In this case, I don't need to send any redirect_uri, because I am reading the response there itself. But I still tried setting an empty value and also tried setting it to some value that **exactly** matches one of the values in google developers console. In that case, I am still getting..

> Error: 400, invalid request; redirect_uri mismatch.

I cannot get my head around the fact that this web service call is working perfectly for android codes and not for web codes. Please note that scopes are different for Android app and Web app. But still, this seems to be some fundamental error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's easy to say that both probably use a different API call, or the android sdk uses a reserved or "magic" redirect url. The thing is, oauth using JavaScript tends to be a flow with the client side involved.